# É possivel cancelar uma transação usando a API do Pagar.me?

Tags: php, aplicação-web

É possivel cancelar uma transação usando a API do Pagar.me ?

Comment: Você tem que perguntar isso no próprio site! ele com certeza informarão o procedimento ...

Answer (score 1):

É possível estornar uma transação via API.

> Para estornar uma transação via API basta seguir a rota:
>   https://docs.pagar.me/api/#estorno-de-transacao.
>
> No caso de uma transação de cartão de crédito, apenas o ID da
>   transação é necessário para efetuar o estorno, caso ele seja total, e
>   o ID da transação + o valor do estorno caso ele seja parcial.
>
> Caso seja uma transação de boleto, será necessário passar os dados da
>   conta bancária que receberá o valor estornado (o estorno funcionará
>   como uma transferência bancária).

**fonte:**
https://pagarme.zendesk.com/hc/pt-br/articles/115000482846-Como-fa%C3%A7o-para-estornar-uma-transa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-via-API-